# Bending with Curve Modifier doesn't follow curve

Tags: mesh, 3d-printing

I am working on a 3D-printable design and am trying to use Blender to simply "bend" a flat object into the shape I need (basically adding two "rounded" 90-degree bends).

I've got:

hex_mesh.stl --  This is the flat object is basically a flat sheet with a lattice of hexagons cut out of it (which I designed in FreeCAD).

[image: Flat Hex Mesh Object]

bend_curve_inner.svg -- This is the shape of that I'd like to bend the hex_mesh.stl into (also designed in FreeCAD).

[image: Curve describing the shape I'd like to bend the Flat Hex Mesh into]

I've imported the hex_mesh.stl as an Object and the bend_curve_inner.svg as a Curve and then:

1. Added a "Remesh" modifier to the Hex Mesh to generate enough vertices for the bend to work with.
2. Added a "Curve" modifier to the Hex Mesh to attempt to bend it into the shape prescribed by the Curve.
3. Messed around with the Hex Mesh origin, Deform Axis, and translation/rotation until I got to the result shown below:

[image: Result -- Curve modifier doesn't really follow the Curve]

This curves correctly around the first bend, but then doesn't follow the straight line or bend around the other portion of the Curve.

[image: Top-down view of result -- doesn't follow the Curve]

Can anyone explain why it's not following the geometry of the Curve?  I've done similar operations before with more complicated curves, but can't figure out why this one isn't working.

Please let me know if you need more information, and thanks for any help!

Comment: Also related with example file https://blenderartists.org/t/curve-deformed-by-curve-no-front-back/513921/4?u=vklidu

Answer (score 0):

More info in comments. Just for you before closing your question and because seeing my answer with A letter I was a bit confused with orientation again ... :)

Here all rotations zero ... just orient your object in **local Y axis** in edit mode.

[image]

Result with *Curve* modifier deformed on *Y axis*

[image]

[image]